# mu4e with default s/mime signature and point

Tags: mu4e, newlines

I write e-mails with mu4e and sign them with an s/mime certificate by default. Do this end, I have defined mu4e with

```
:enter-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Switch to work context") (add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook 'mml-secure-message-sign-smime) )
```

So that whenever I enter mu4e-compose-mode to write a new message, or a reply to one, mml-secure-message-sign-smime is executed. When I reply to an e-mail from, say, alice@mail.com, then I get an e-mail compose buffer, which looks like this:

```
From: My Name <my@email.com>
To: alice@mail.com
Subject: Re: hi!
Date: Mon, 29 Jan 2024 17:15:39 +0100
--text follows this line--
<#secure method=smime mode=sign>

On 2024-01-29 at 17:11 +01, "Alice" <alice@mail.com> wrote...
> Hi!
```

It is now very annoying that whenever I reply to an e-mail, then the point, i.e. the cursor, is now right before the <#secure. Hence, when I start typing, I write the text immediately before the <#secure...>. However, it seems that it is important that the e-mail body begins with the string <#secure method=smime mode=sign>, it cannot be anywhere else in the e-mail body, as otherwise it is interpreted as text that is sent along with the rest of the message.

I tried to fix this by additionally adding the following code to the mu4e-compose-mode-hook:

```
:enter-func (lambda () (mu4e-message "Switch to work context") (add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook 'mml-secure-message-sign-smime) (add-hook 'mu4e-compose-mode-hook (lambda () (forward-line 1))))
```

With this I want to move the cursor to the next line after <#secure ... >. Unfortunately, this has no effect, the cursor remains before the  <#secure ... > sting.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thank you very much for your help!